# Search with result priority based on different condtions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a auto-complete search box that I am working on for a client. The database is in SQL Server and there is a big set of data.

I've been able to do a standard LIKE query to the database which is not that much of a problem, but the client has come up with some requirements.

Let's say the search keyword is "London Airport"

The results that show up must have certain precedence. Here are the precedence criteria:

1. The results with London and Airport as match must show at the top. e.g. London Airport, London Main Airport etc.
2. The results with London must follow, since it matches the city field.
3. Airport would then follow, as it is the catagory part.

The requirement is actually to include UK results first but I have already taken care of that.

Let's say the table is

Airport_name | country | city | geo_id  and so on.

I've created a table function that splits the keyword into table rows of results and then I've done the like query 
LIKE '% split_table.result %'

the trouble is even for the 1st criteria, the above approach is doing an OR query, showing results with London and Airport only... I want to do an AND query here and would appreciate it if I could use the split table function I've created.

I need some idea about how to set these priorities.

I'd really appropriate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One plan of action is to build the separate result sets and union them together

```
select Id, Name
from
    (
         Select Id, Name, 1 as SearchRank from tables where (primary filter)
         union 
         Select Id, Name, 2 as SearchRank from tables where (secondary filter)
         union 
         Select Id, Name, 3 as SearchRank from tables where (tertiary filter)
    ) results
group by Id, Name
order by Min(SearchRank)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps as you are using sql server

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142559%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: I cannot use Full text search as the database is not full text indexed and we're too deep into development phase.